# catch mysql-exception using .Number

Tags: c#, mysql, database, exception, visual-studio-2012

I want to catch a specific mysql error with the number 1046.
If i use MessageBox.Show to display the error number it is always 0, no matter which Exception it is. Shouldn't the Exception have a number like the number 1046?

```
catch (MySqlException mysqlex)
{ 
    MessageBox.Show(mysqlex.Number.ToString());
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, i am using the MySQL-Connector / Net.

Comment: @GrantWinney Nope, that is a standard class contained in the Mysql.Data connector (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlexceptionmembers.html)

Comment: Write mysqlex.Message in message box. What it says ?

Comment: In fact Number property is with capital http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlexceptionmembers.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlexception-number. Can you paste the real code ? This won't compile IMO.

Comment: And indeed `Number` should start with a capital.

Comment: i corrected that. If i use mysqlex.Message i get the No database selected. That's the exception i want to catch.

Comment: If error number is 0, the client is not able to connect to the server. Can you see if you have an inner exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see a number because you did not connect to a database. 
And probably MySQL is assigning numbers to error exceptions.

If you look at description for Number property [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlexceptionmembers.html) it says

> Gets a number that identifies the type of error. This number corresponds to the error numbers given in **Server** Error Codes and Messages.

Because you did not made a connection to the server you cannot get server error code.

Check your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Probably same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899020/c-sharp-mysql-connector-number-always-0).

please try in the following code.

MessageBox.Show(mysqlex.InnnerException.Number.ToString());

Comment: This should probably be a comment to the question; you should include an explanation and a reference to the documentation to produce a good quality answer, not just a link to your own answer (e.g. explain why the `InnerException` property needs to be queried to obtain the number).

Comment: I'm truly sorry.
An addition of a answer is added.
Thank you very much for pointing out a problem of my answer.